# Turn array of objects into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of branches that looks roughly like this:

```js
let branches = [
  {
    id: 21,
    name: "Branch 1",
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name "Branch 2"
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  // .. etc
]
```

But I'd like to turn it into an object with the name as the key for each.

#### Desired output:

```
branches = {
  "Branch 1": {
    id: 21,
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  "Branch 2": {
    id: 22,
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  }
}
```

#### Tried:

```js
let newBranches = branches.map(branch => (
  {
    [branch.name]: {
      id: branch.id,
      days: branch.opening_times
    }
  }
));
console.log(newBranches)
```

But of course mapping gives me an array output:

```js
[
  0: {Branch 1: {…}}
  1: {Branch 2: {…}}
]
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get a new object with the `name` key as an object itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use a simple `for-of` loop. You'll get `reduce` answers, but all `reduce` does here is add complexity.

```
const result = {};
for (const {name, id, opening_times} of branches) {
  result[name] = {id, opening_times};
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let branches = [
  {
    id: 21,
    name: "Branch 1",
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name: "Branch 2",
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  // .. etc
];
const result = {};
for (const {name, id, opening_times} of branches) {
  result[name] = {id, opening_times};
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Adding in [Code Maniac's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439738/turn-array-of-objects-into-an-object/56439789#comment99473415_56439789) of using rest:

```
const result = {};
for (const {name, ...entry} of branches) {
  result[name] = entry;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let branches = [
  {
    id: 21,
    name: "Branch 1",
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name: "Branch 2",
    opening_times: [ {}, {}, {} ] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  // .. etc
];
const result = {};
for (const {name, ...entry} of branches) {
  result[name] = entry;
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Those are slightly different, in that the first one *explicitly* only uses `id` and `opening_times` in the result, but the rest version uses all properties other than `name`. And of course, there's a difference in readability (explicit vs. implicit), but there are places I'd use each of them.

Comment: Love the readability compared to the reduce methods. Any idea which would be faster though?

Comment: ***On side note:-*** i guess we can use `rest parameter` here instead of taking all the properties out and than creating object again, i.e `for (const {name, ...rest} of branches)`

Comment: @EliNathan - On modern JavaScript engines I expect it's a wash. `for-of` creates and uses an iterator (subject to optimization, which JavaScript engines can definitely do), which involves function calls. `reduce` doesn't use an iterator, but has calls to the callback. So...

Comment: @EliNathan - And of course, you'd have to have at least tens of thousands of entries in `branches` for it to matter (or you'd have to be doing this over and over again in a tight loop).

Comment: Actually going to use the explicit versions here as I simplified the `branches` array down for the purposes of this question. It has a lot of stuff in it that I don't need to add into my new object. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With a simple `reduce()` operation and object destructuring:

```js
const branches = [{
    id: 21,
    name: "Branch 1",
    opening_times: []
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name: "Branch 2",
    opening_times: []
  }
];

const result = branches.reduce((a, {name, ...v}) => (a[name] = v, a), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why not just `a[name] = v`?

Comment: @adiga OP indicates that the `name` property should not be in the value object.

Comment: I meant `(a[name] = v, a)` instead of `(a[name] = {...v}, a)`

Comment: @adiga I know what you meant. Doing it that way would include the `name` property in the value object.

Comment: But destructuring already takes care of that right? `v` is already a new object without a `name` property. `{...v}` is just cloning `v`

Comment: @adiga Wow. Sorry. I think my brain must have short-circuited there. Thanks a lot. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign all object by spreading new object with the wanted key of `name` and the rest of the object.

```js
let branches = [{ id: 21, name: "Branch 1", opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] }, { id: 22, name: "Branch 2", opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] }],
    newBranches = Object.assign({}, ...branches.map(({ name, ...o }) => ({ [name]: o })));

console.log(newBranches);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
let branches = [{ id: 21, name: "Branch 1", opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] }, { id: 22, name: "Branch 2", opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] }],
    newBranches = Object.fromEntries(branches.map(({ name, ...o }) => [name, o]));

console.log(newBranches);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why your every answer is so complicated? ,A new user who just understands the for loop won't even have a slight idea what's going here,can you just bit more simplify things.

Comment: @Shubh I've been seeing Nina Scholz's answers for a couple of years now, and they are consistently the best performing, and often the most creative solutions for any given problem. Stack Overflow does not only aim to be a knowledge repository for beginners.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen,yeah same here but I guess there should be some bit elaboration or some helper links to the new fellow users ,that just  widens the horizon for understanding.

Answer (score 4):

ES 2019 draft provides [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) for this exact purpose:

```
result = Object.fromEntries(branches.map(({name,...rest}) => [name, rest]))
```

It's already implemented in most browsers, but the polyfill is easy:

```
Object.fromEntries = iter =>
    Object.assign({},
        ...[...iter].map(
            ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})
        ));
```

Comment: You need to remove `name` property from value, to match expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`.

```js
let branches = [{id:21,name:"Branch 1",opening_times:[{},{},{}]},{id:22,name:"Branch 2" ,opening_times:[{},{},{}]}];
const res = branches.reduce((acc, { name, ...rest }) => (acc[name] = { ...rest }, acc), {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var branches = [{id:21,name:"Branch 1",opening_times:[{},{},{}]},{id:22,name:"Branch 2" ,opening_times:[{},{},{}]}];
var res = branches.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr.name] = { id: curr.id, opening_times: curr.opening_times };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let branches = [{
    id: 21,
    name: "Branch 1",
    opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    name: "Branch 2",
    opening_times: [{}, {}, {}] // Array of objects (Monday, Tuesday etc)
  }
]

let newBranches = {};

branches.forEach((el) => {
  newBranches[el.name] = {
    id: el.id,
    opening_times: el.opening_times
  };
});

console.log(newBranches)
```

Comment: I guess ,its never a good idea to define a global variable and change its value in a loop ,that may cause wrong outputs if we have a complicated code structure

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (ES6)

```
Object.assign({}, ...array.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item })));
```